# How to convert db BLOB column to a byte[] with EntityManager without defining @Entity?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I need to pull a BLOB field out of an Oracle database.  I'm using Spring with EntityManager, but I don't want to go through all the effort of defining an @Entity object to represent the table.

I did this something like this ...

```
String sql = "select * from MY_TABLE where ID = '"+id+"'";
List<Object> resultList = em.createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList();
for (Object o : resultList) {
    try {
        if (o != null) {
            Object[] element = (Object[])o;
            byte[] data = (byte[])element[1];
        }
```

... but the problem is the "element[1]" is a "SerialBlobProxy" object, not the array of bytes.

Is there a simple way to convert that "element[1]" into an array of byte[]?

Answer (score 0):

Do Spring JPA allow unwrapping underlying entitymanager connection, then run *low-level* jdbc resultset and getters. Connection instance you get depends on whether JPA transaction is active or not.

```
Connection con = em.unwrap(Connection.class);
```

If you have `started EM transaction you get the same connection so be careful not to close,commit,rollback this too soon.` You may want to use EM methods finalising transaction. Unwrapping connection without active transaction creates a new instance so caller must close this connection.

There is nothing wrong with using jdbc classes within JPA application, high-level interface may not always suit best all tasks. JPA spec owners know it and lucky to us does not enforce it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  My actual code is a little more complex than my simplified example above.  Assume I don't have access with the em ... Is there anything I can do directly with the "element[1]" object to get a byte[] from it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes spring does support JDBC template, if you want to bypass using entity manager for your solution. First configure  your datasource in spring-config. Make your DAO class extend `JdbcDaoSupport` (yeah don't forget to inject configured datasource in DAO). With spring JDBC template you could use native queries and also provide custom RowMapper which could be used to map each row to any type. In your case you could read blob as an input stream from database. See following example:

```
public static class BlobRowMapper implements RowMapper<InputStream> {
        @Override
        public InputStream mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return rs.getBinaryStream("blob_column");
        }
    }
```

You only have to pass your row mapper to query method. See following snippet:

```java
List<InputStream> rows = getJdbcTemplate().query(query, new Object[] {args}, new BlobRowMapper());
```

You'll have to read the bytes from input stream.